# htaccess rewrite rules in separate directories

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a directory called "private". You can access the index.php file by using the url

> http://www.example.com/private/

The index.php looks for the "page" parameter to require_once() the requested page.

> http://www.example.com/private/?page=archive.

I wanted to make a rewrite rule to return the same query when user types:

> http://www.example.com/private/archive.

I tried this rule but it doesn't seem to work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^private/([a-z]+)/?$ private/?page=$1 [L]
```

The .htaccess doesn't want to work if I put it inside the "private" folder or the site's root. Isn't it suppose to be in the "private" folder instead of the root? My rewrite module is on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot to add "RewriteBase"

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /private/

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ ?page=$1 [L]
```

There's no need to write "private/" in the rewrite rule since the rewrite base has been set to it. The .htaccess file should be inside the private folder of course.